# Synchronization problem with Visual Studio 2017 and Unity 2017.1.1f

Tags: unity, visual-studio

Sometimes I need to change a lot of files and Clean and Rebuild the Solution to get the changes on Unity, am I missing some configuration on Visual Studio or Unity? I uninstalled everything and make a clean install and few days later I'm getting the same problems.

Sometimes if I create a stardard MonoBehaviour script from Unity and I try to attack it to a gameObject I get the error: "Can't add script component XXXXXX because the script class can't be found"(see image: [screenshot](https://s1.postimg.org/99l3lxh327/Unity-_Update_Error.png)). The class name and file name are the same, with no syntax errors.

Some times opening a file with an external editor changing the encoding, cleaning and rebuilding the project solves the problem, but just sometimes and I'm tired of do that for test any change, now I have a lot of Debug.Log just to check if Unity is getting my code changes.

Any suggestion will be very greatful

Comment: Not sure if it's the same as what I was experiencing...  I had a few issues a few months back where Visual Studio Intellisense would just not work for any new script created in Unity.  Closing and re-opening it never fixed it.  Sometimes it would just start working again, but it was annoying.  I then came across a solution here (see the accepted answer) https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130597/unity-intellisense-not-working-after-creating-new-1.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no configuration that I can think of but I fix this problem by creating and deleting my scripts inside of visual studio. If you have your VS working with Unity then you should be able to create a "MonoBehaviour" script within the IDE itself.